# How to change font size in Index in memoir class?

Tags: memoir, fontsize, indexing

Each time I build the index with `makeindex` I have to insert `\footnotesize` after `\begin{theindex}` in book.ind file. I use `memoir` class. Is there an automatic way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use my [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package (which is compatible with `memoir`) and its `font` option. Allowed values are `normalsize`, `small`, `footnotesize`, and `current` (the font in effect at the time of `\printindex`). (You may also redefine the `\indexfont` macro if you need a more exotic fontsize.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeindex

\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

Some text about foo\index{foo}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Note that the `memoir` class, according to section 17.2 of its manual, features a `\preindexhook` macro that does nothing by default, but may be redefined to, e.g., `\footnotesize`. Therefore, on the face of it, loading `idxlayout` is superfluous. However, in `memoir`'s implementation of the `theindex` environment, `\preindexhook` is part of the optional argument of `\twocolumn` for two-column indexes, and because of that, switching to `\footnotesize` will only affect an index preamble note, but not the index proper. (The latter *is* affected if you switch to a one-column index, though.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeindex

% \onecolindex
\renewcommand{\preindexhook}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

Some text about foo\index{foo}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```